# Redux-orm not calling mapStateToProps after adding data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-orm

I am playing around with redux-orm and after adding an entity my selector is not updating with the new objects in mapStateToProps, hence resulting in render() not being called again. I've been through the tutorials but cannot see what I am doing wrong:

Another component is calling the BookReducer, so I know 100% the reducer is being called.

Here is my reducer:

```
export default function BookReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    const session = orm.session(state);

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'newBook':

            session.Book.create({ id: 0, type: 'novel' });

            //I can see verify that the object has been added  to the ORM
            console.log(session.Book.all().toRefArray())
     }

     return session.state; 
}
```

Here is my selector:

```
import orm from './orm';

const BookSelector = createSelector(orm, state => state.orm, session => {
    return session.Book.all().toRefArray()
});
```

Here is my component:

```
class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {

    console.log("debug")
    console.log(this.props.books)

    return (
       <div>
           {this.props.books}
       </div>
    )


    function mapStateToProps(state) {

       return {
          isOpen: true,
          books: BookSelector(state)
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed Redux chrome plugin? Could you confirm with it that in your store you correctly have the new book in your store? Problem could be in your reducer if not correctly called with your store

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have connected the Main compnent with `mapStateToProps` . USe `connect` like `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);` and define it outside the `Main` component

```
import connect from 'react-redux';

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {

    console.log("debug")
    console.log(this.props.books)

    return (
       <div>
           {this.props.books}
       </div>
    )



}

  function mapStateToProps(state) {

       return {
          isOpen: true,
          books: BookSelector(state)
       };
    }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

Also you need to export and import the `BookSelector`

```
import orm from './orm';

const BookSelector = createSelector(orm, state => state.orm, session => {
    return session.Book.all().toRefArray()
});
export default BookSelector;
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, the component was connected with connect(mapStateToProps)(Main), sorry forgot to paste that in. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Lance, As suggested, keep your mapStateToProps function outside of the component and are you wrapping your components in a provider tag

Comment: hi Shubham, mapStateToProps is outside of the component, but not helping. MapStateToProps is working with state changes on other test components changing state (non redux-orm), it only fails to see changes from redux-orm. And yes the root index.js wraps everything in a provider with the store.

Comment: You haven't exported you bookselector component

Comment: Hi Shubham, apologies it was exported. I think I would get an error if it couldnt call it at all. It's just whenever the selector is called it always returns 0 values. If I put debug statements inside the selector to see the state or to print I also get 0 values.

Comment: Shubham, so mapStateToProps is being called every time I run the reducer, in the reducer console log I can see the session object changing with new items. But the selector is always returning 0 objects. Since mapStateToProps is being called that means state is changing somewhere, but for some reason it still returns 0 items?